# Pyspark changing type of column from date to string

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
corr_temp_df
[('vacationdate', 'date'),
 ('valueE', 'string'),
 ('valueD', 'string'),
 ('valueC', 'string'),
 ('valueB', 'string'),
 ('valueA', 'string')]
```

Now I would like to change the datatype of the column vacationdate to String, so that also the dataframe takes this new type and overwrites the datatype data for all of the entries. E.g. after writing:

```
corr_temp_df.dtypes
```

The datatype of vacationdate should be overwritten.

I already used functions like cast, StringType or astype, but I was not successful. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lets create some dummy data:

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

row = Row("vacationdate")

df = sc.parallelize([
    row(datetime.date(2015, 10, 07)),
    row(datetime.date(1971, 01, 01))
]).toDF()
```

If you Spark >= 1.5.0 you can use `date_format` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

(df
   .select(date_format(col("vacationdate"), "dd-MM-YYYY")
   .alias("date_string"))
   .show())
```

In Spark < 1.5.0 it can be done using Hive UDF:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql(
    "SELECT date_format(vacationdate, 'dd-MM-YYYY') AS date_string FROM df")
```

It is of course still available in Spark >= 1.5.0.

If you don't use `HiveContext` you can mimic `date_format` using UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, lit
my_date_format = udf(lambda d, fmt: d.strftime(fmt))

df.select(
    my_date_format(col("vacationdate"), lit("%d-%m-%Y")).alias("date_string")
).show()
```

Please note it is using [C standard format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) not a Java [simple date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)