# pyspark - 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following summary for dataset, using pyspark on databricks

| OrderMonthYear | SaleAmount |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-11-01T00:00:00.000+0000 | 473760.5700000001 |
| 2010-04-01T00:00:00.000+0000 | 490967.0900000001 |

I'm having dataframe error for this map function to convert OrderMonthYear into integer type

```
results = summary.map(lambda r: (int(r.OrderMonthYear.replace('-','')), r.SaleAmount)).toDF(["OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount"])
```

any ideas?

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Comment: you can't convert that to an integer because there are strings that you didn't replace (T, +, :)

Comment: hey, thx for reply, the column is a timestamp.. not string   DataFrame[OrderMonthYear: timestamp]

Comment: then why are you calling `replace`? that's a string method.

Comment: got it. even when I try to use datetime functions doesn't work.   .....  test = summary.select("OrderMonthYear").apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%m%Y'))      .....                           'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply' .... I guess my sql call is confusing the dataframe structure? .. . data = sqlContext.read.format("csv")

Comment: what's your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here [Pyspark date yyyy-mmm-dd conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607059/pyspark-date-yyyy-mmm-dd-conversion)

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp, from_unixtime, date_format
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

df = summary.withColumn('date', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("OrderMonthYear", 'yyyy-MMM')))


df2 = df.withColumn("new_date_str", date_format(col("date"), "yyyyMMdd"))
display(df2)
```

thank you @mck for the help!
cheers