# Date Format conversion in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string column in df which contains date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format and I want to convert that format to `yyyy-MM-dd` using with column

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will have a consistent format in your column, you can pass this to 'to_datetime'.

You can try like below-

```
df['column_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'], format='%d/%m/%y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: it is pyspark dataframe not pandas

Comment: PySpark SQL function provides to_date() function to convert String to Date fromat of a DataFrame column.   to_date() – function is used to format string (StringType) to date (DateType) column. Refer to [Link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-to_date-convert-string-to-date-format/)

Answer (score 0):

Using python's datetime lib it can be done accordingly:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '10/10/2000'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y')
converted_date_string = datetime_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: its a pyspark not pandas df

Comment: Could the answer to this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607059/pyspark-date-yyyy-mmm-dd-conversion Something along this line- `df = df.withColumn('date_col', f.udf(lambda d: strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), t.StringType())(f.col('date_col')))`