# Convert string to date in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a date value in a column of string type that takes this format:

06-MAY-16 09.17.15

I want to convert it to this format:

20160506

I have tried using `DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE(<column>), 'yyyyMMdd')` but a `NULL` value is returned.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to go about doing this in pyspark or spark SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark date yyyy-mmm-dd conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607059/pyspark-date-yyyy-mmm-dd-conversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it!  This is the code I used which seems to have worked:

`FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<column>, 'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss'), 'yyyyMMdd')`

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Your original attempt is close to the solution. You just needed to add the format in the TO_DATE() function. This will work as well:

```
DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE(<col>, 'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss'), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

And for pyspark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('<col>', F.date_format(F.to_date(F.col('<col>'), 'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss'), 'yyyyMMdd'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to a date before you try to 'reformat' it.

- [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format) -- `to_timestamp(df.t, 'dd-MMM-YY HH.mm.ss').alias('my_date')`
- [Pyspark date yyyy-mmm-dd conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607059/pyspark-date-yyyy-mmm-dd-conversion) -- `date_format(col("my_date"), "yyyyMMdd")`